# Javascript Pop-Up when Mouse Hovers toward Browser Bar/Back Button

Tags: javascript, popup, hover, mouseover

I would like to imitate this exact feature on this page. 
(Move mouse toward the top browser bar)

http://my-personal-growth.com/personal-growth/what-anthony-robbins-teaches-about-emotions-and-meaning

I guess all i need to know is how to create the hovering mouse action, the rest I should be able to handle myself.

Any tutorials? I don't know js.

Thanks Everyone.

Comment: This is one of the most f**ing annoying JavaScript functions I have ever seen.

Comment: To answer your question though, I strongly doubt whether there are tutorials out there for this specific purpose. You may need to implement this for yourself. It's not difficult, but it's a really bad idea.

Comment: I'm with @Pekka, don't do this, I'd be ready to hunt you down with torches and pitchforks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use window.onmouseout event or use onmouseout on the elements on the page you are using.

Something like this:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>onmouseout test</title>

<style type="text/css">
.my_box { border: 1px solid red; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onmouseout = mouseout;

function mouseout()
{
 alert("mouseout event detected!");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="my_box">
<p>move the mouse pointer away from the element it is on<br />
to fire the mouseout event.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You might notice the wee little text at the bottom of the (**f&!ing**) popup:

> <sup>[Powered by ActionPopup](http://www.actionpopup.com/?hop=kgs03)</sup>

That's how it's done.

Don't do it.

(And don't you just *love* the voice that starts talking at you when you open the ActionPopup page?)

Comment: Oh my God. There is an actual company that does this? Oh, and they have a auto-play video pop-up at full volume to show you how great it is.

Comment: @PEKKA: INORITE, WE ALL SHOULD GLUE OUR CAPSLOCK KEYS IN THE "ON" POSITION AND ALSO LITTER OUR WEBSITES WITH `<BLINK>` AND `<MARQUEE>` and... wait... that didn't come out right at _all_

Answer (score 1):

As Matt Ball said, it's made by [ActionPopup](http://www.actionpopup.com).

If you want to see how it's done, you can have a look at the code here :

http://my-personal-growth.com/wp-content/plugins/action-popup/actionpopup.php

(not sure why it has a php extension...)

But as the others said, it is a very annoying function. I can't really see how it would ever be useful.