# detect if user is hovering over browser back button

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-handling

I think I am asking the wrong question, i.e. it is being phrased wrong because I cannot find an answer to this issue and I cannot be the first person to ask this question here....

---

Aim: When the user moves the mouse over the back button (history.back) do something.

Why: When the user moves the mouse over the back button or towards the back button have a model pop up with a site offer.

---

Questions:

Is there a selector for the back button so I could do something along the lines of:

1. get back button X and Y cords
2. get mouse button X and Y cords
3. Compare and if equal - do something

Open to suggestions, as I mentioned I cannot be the first person to ask this question but oddly cannot seem to find a previous answer.

Thanks - W

Comment: Unless the back button is in your HTML, then no.

Comment: As @Paulie_D said, you can't do that with the **browser's** back button. Separately, some feedback for your management team: when a website does the next nearest thing (detecting when I move the mouse up to the top of the page) and does one of those irritating "It looks like you're leaving!" popups when I move the mouse past the top of the page, the website goes on my list of sites **never to visit again**. Present your offers in a normal way on the page.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yes, I know what your talking about, thanks for the input

Comment: You could detect the mouseleave on html element - you don't know if they are hovering over the back button or something else but you know they may be thinking about it. And it would sort of work wherever the browser places its back button. However, I'm with @T.J.Crowder on this - it seems rather 'intrusive'. And thankfully touch screen users won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this behavior is achieved by listening for the `onmousemove` event and calculating from that if the mouse is approaching, for example, top left portion of the screen. What comes to browser buttons, I don't believe there's a specific event for them, as browsers come in different shapes, forms and functionalities.

I found a similar question here in Stackoverflow, which might lead to you a right direction: [Javascript Pop-Up when Mouse Hovers toward Browser Bar/Back Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054867/javascript-pop-up-when-mouse-hovers-toward-browser-bar-back-button). Based on the comments some users seem to find the behavior you're looking for a bit frustrating, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Thta's not "similar," it's a duplicate target. When you find a dupetarget, mark the question as a duplicate of that question, rather than posting an answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks @T.J.Crowder for the info, will do that next time.